# How include SVG default proposals into Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, svg

I am started studying SVG graphics.
I create namespace for SVG in my project in Eclipse. But when I press `CTRL + SPACE` there don't exist default proposals?
**How include them into Eclipse?**

My first html file (It's works, but I have several warning `Unknown tag (rect/svg).` any ideas why they occurs???)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="10" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="5" ry="5"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
  <rect x="70" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="10" ry="10"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
  <rect x="130" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="15" ry="15"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I tried this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg:svg>
  <svg:rect x="10" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="5" ry="5"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
  <svg:rect x="70" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="10" ry="10"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
  <svg:rect x="130" y="10" height="50" width="50" rx="15" ry="15"
   style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00" />
 </svg:svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Warnings don't occurs, but this doesn't work(